# Adding a description to a Facebook Application

Tags: facebook

How can i add a description to a Facebook application? It seems there is no way to do it.i can only manage the title, url, but no description. I know this was possible before, as i see description on other Facebook applications.And there is no info about this.
 Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check it 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/
    there is provision for you to add description about your app.